# Error when trying to play audio in swift using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm pretty new to coding and I've attempted to implement the code suggested in other answers to similar questions on here with no luck. The app builds fine but every time I go to play the actual audio file I get an error message saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)" while it highlights the `audioPlayer.play()` line.

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3"),
            let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath) {
                var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathURL, error: nil)

        }else{
            println("the filePath is empty OR the file did not load")
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

Comment: Then there should be a location error, check the mp3 file path that it exist inside your project. try to add before `audioPlayer.play()` ->             `audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete working code for play audio and stop audio:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var playAudio: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopAudio: UIButton!

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer? = AVAudioPlayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("we_cant_Stop", ofType: "mp3")!)
        var error : NSError?

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
        if let err = error{
            println("audioPlayer error \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            audioPlayer?.delegate = self
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let player = audioPlayer{
            player.play()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func stopTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let player = audioPlayer {
            player.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Check [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/audioPlayer-App-with-swift) sample project for more Info.

Comment: Appreciate the response! I'm having the same issue as the other response... timeouts. Is this a problem with the file and not the code? "10:22:01.630 ERROR:     185: timeout
10:22:01.631 ERROR:     240: CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
2015-08-03 10:22:12.864 Udacity[24178:686720] 10:22:12.864 ERROR:     185: timeout"

Comment: May be there is a problem with file try to replace your file with another and you can test my sample project too.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work fine :

```
        var soundURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3")!)!
        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I attempted to add your suggestions and there are no errors in code now but every time I hit the play button it times out. The error messages I have now are: "10:01:56.367 ERROR:     185: timeout
10:01:56.368 ERROR:     240: CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
10:02:07.852 ERROR:     185: timeout"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` in your class. I think this should be the main problem.

In addition you should also include `prepareToPlay()` in your 
Function

```
@IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```